# DNS propagation

Tags: linux, domain-name-system

I have 1 primary DNS server (ns1.mydomain.com) running on Fedora and 2 secondary ones (ns2 and ns3). DNS changes made on my web servers first goes to the primary name server and then propagates to the  secondary servers. After making a DNS change on a domain on the web server, I  can't see the new dns information on my ns1 when I perform:

```
dig @ns1 A blahblah.com
```

I then went to the master records on the names server (uses named) in the directory `/var/named/run-root/var/named/masters` and I see the A record has been updated appropriately.

Tailing the logs `/var/log/messages` is not showing any errors. What could be the issue?

Comment: if you can't see new info on master then likely after making the change you didn't reload the zone ; try rndc reload blahblah.com and make sure you incremented serial in zone afer the change so slaves pick up the change

Answer (score 1):

Have you incremented serial number?